# Single .exe file is too large

Tags: c#, exe, .net-5

I am trying to create a single file executable in C#. However I don't like how large the file is. A simple Hello World program is 20mb on its own. Is there a good way to shrink the size of this, perhaps by removing things the program does not use.

Below is my .csproj file for the Hello World test program. I would also like to state I am editing in Release mode if this makes a difference

```
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>

    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
```

Comment: You can use [Invariant Globalization](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/globalization-invariant-mode.md) mode, which removes a bunch of globalization stuff you might not care about. You could also stop bundling the .NET Runtime which will reduce the size significantly, but this will of course mean that it needs to be installed on the user's machine by another means

Comment: 20mb is large? many python programmers still use pyinstaller to pack their scripts(several kb) to generate a 100Mb exe. every coin has two sides.

Comment: Not sure why you're seeing 20MB, but it might be because you're on .NET 5. If I run `dotnet publish --configuration=Release` on a trimmed single-file .NET 6 Hello World project, it's 11MB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, try upgrading to .NET 6 if you can. A trimmed self-contained single-file .NET 6 Hello World console app is ~11MB, not 20MB.

To go further, you can try disabling framework features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options#trimming-framework-library-features

You can compress assemblies, although this comes with a performance cost at runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview#compress-assemblies-in-single-file-app

And if you need to go even further, soon you'll be able to do AOT compilation using NativeAOT; this will build much smaller executables as they do not need to include the JIT compiler. NativeAOT will be shipping with .NET 7; keep an eye on the .NET 7 preview releases for instructions.

You may find this blog post on the topic useful: https://www.awise.us/2021/06/05/smallest-dotnet.html

Comment: Thankyou for this answer and the links, it helped me alot with my problem